# How to Create a counter Loop that starts when submit button is clicked and outputs multiple lines of words with a number in front of each word?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, button, counter

I need to create a counter loop that begins after the user clicks the "submit" button. However, this "submit" button is already being used in another variable. The submit button needs to do two things here, at the same time, and I cannot figure out how to make that work. When the user inputs their information for their first name, last name, and middle initial, and then clicks the submit button, not only will the header change, but a counter to 125 needs to begin. Here is my code so far. What changes do I need to make sure that when the user clicks submit, the `<h1>` changes with their name in the greeting, and a loop begins counting from 1 to 125 with words like "hello world" after it.

example:
1)Hello World
2)Hello World
3)Hello World
etc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fizzbuzz.css">
  <title>Fizz Buzz 0</title>

  <script>
    function clickFunction(){
      var firstName =  document.getElementById("firstName").value;
      var middleName=  document.getElementById("middleName").value;
      var lastName=    document.getElementById("lastName").value;
      document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML =
        "Welcome, " + firstName + " " + middleName+ " " +lastName + "!";
    };

    function clickFunction = ""; {
      while (var i=0;i<125;i++) {
        out = out + "London Kings" + "</br>";
        document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = out;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <p>
      <img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="Banner" height="130" width="940" style="border:0" />
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="content">  
    <div id="feature">
      <h2 id="greeting"> Welcome to London Kings Football! </h2> 
      <form>
        First Name <input id="firstName"> </input>
        Middle Initial <input id="middleName"> </input>
        Last Name <input id="lastName"> </input>
      </form>
      <button onClick="clickFunction()",> Submit </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some changes you can make to make to your current code so it runs

1. change the while loop to a for loop
2. initialize the out variable ( you are using it before it is defined
   in a right hand assignmen)

So you final function is

```
function clickFunction() {

  var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
  var middleName = document.getElementById("middleName").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
  var out = '';

  document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Welcome, " + firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName + "!";


  for (var i = 0; i < 125; i++) {
    out = out + "London Kings" + "</br>";
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = out;
  }
}
```

**Other things that could make your code better**

1. Dont add the event listener inline, its harder to reason for your code
   instead use `document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){});`
2. move your script tag just before the closing body tag (`</body>`) this way the javascript code parsing will not block the rendering of the page (js runs in one thread)
3. dont query the DOM for each repetition of the for loop instead move the greeting query to the top of the function so you run it only once (per function call)
4. dont query for the DOM elements each time you run the code(better solution to 3 above, instead either move queries to the top level (those vars will be global, we dont like globals) or create a closure which will encapsulate your valiables

### #4 example

```
var clickFunction = (function(){
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
    var middleName = document.getElementById("middleName");
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName");
    var greeting = document.getElementById("greeting");
    var out = '';

    return function(){
      greeting.innerHTML = "Welcome, " + firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName + "!";
      for (var i = 0; i < 125; i++) {
        out = out + "London Kings" + "</br>";
        greeting.innerHTML = out;
      }
    }

  }())

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", clickFunction)
```

***script tag containing the above code has to be before the closing body tag***

Comment: The counter works when I do that, but thats all the script does. It does not also print "Welcome firstName, lastName, middleInitial" when I do that. also it prints the counter inside of my h2 and i would like the counter to be underneath the welcome greeting.

Comment: creating a span to hold all the counter text could do the work. here is a working example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPrpQb?editors=1010